# Python & Pygame - I am trying to make window and player that can move (WASD), but it makes only black window.

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, 2d-games, python-3.6

I am working on easier way to make sprites in pygame (It's only for me). I have this 3 files

file 1: Tests.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import MySprites
import SpecialFunctions

Sprites = []

NewScreen = SpecialFunctions.Level('NewProject', '2D-AboveView', (960, 540), Sprites)

Sprites = []

imgDolu = [pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-8.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-9.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-10.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-11.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-12.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-13.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-14.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-15.png')]
imgNahoru = [pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-0.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-1.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-2.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-3.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-4.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-5.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-6.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-1-7.png')]
imgDoleva = [pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-0.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-1.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-2.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-3.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-4.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-5.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-6.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-7.png')]
imgDoprava = [pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-8.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-9.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-10.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-11.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-12.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-13.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-14.png'), pygame.image.load('HeroSprites/HeroSpriteSheet2 [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-15.png')]
imgUtociNahoru = []; imgUtociDolu = []; imgUtociDoleva = []; imgUtociDoprava = []
Player1 = MySprites.Player_Type_AboveView(movingUp=imgNahoru, movingDown=imgDolu, movingLeft=imgDoleva, movingRight=imgDoprava, swingingUp=imgUtociNahoru, swingingDown=imgUtociDolu, swingingLeft=imgUtociDoleva, swingingRight=imgUtociDoprava, controlUp=pygame.K_w, controlDown=pygame.K_s, controlLeft=pygame.K_a, controlRight=pygame.K_d, controlSwing=pygame.K_k, speed=5, x=960/2, y=540/2)
Sprites.append(Player1)

NewScreen.mainloop()
```

Thats my general file, this is where I am testing.

file 2: SpecialFunctions.py:

```
import pygame
import MySprites
from pygame.locals import *

class Level:
    def __init__(self, Name, Type, screen_size, AllSprites):

        """Inicialization of Project"""

        black = (0, 0, 0)
        screen_size = screen_size
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
        pygame.display.set_caption(Name)
        self.screen.fill(black)
        pygame.display.update()
        self.ProjectSprites = AllSprites

        self.Running = True

        self.type = Type

        self.keys_pressed_list = []

    def screen_Update(self):
        if self.Running:
            self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            for sprite in self.ProjectSprites:
                sprite.update(sprite, self.screen)
                sprite.draw(self.screen)
            pygame.display.update()

    def mainloop(self):

        """Running program"""

        while self.Running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    self.Running = False
                    break
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    self.keys_pressed_list.append(event.key)
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    self.keys_pressed_list.remove(event.key)
            if self.Running:
                self.screen_Update()
            pygame.time.delay(100)
```

This is file with some tools that I can use for my screen.

file 3: MySprites.py:

```
import pygame

class Player_Type_AboveView (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,
             movingUp, movingDown, movingLeft, movingRight,
             swingingUp, swingingDown, swingingLeft, swingingRight,
             controlUp, controlDown, controlLeft, controlRight, controlSwing,
             speed, x, y):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        #Player controls:
        self.controls_Up = controlUp
        self.controls_Down = controlDown
        self.controls_Left = controlLeft
        self.controls_Right = controlRight
        self.controls_Swing = controlSwing

        #Player textures:
        self.imgUp = movingUp
        self.imgDown = movingDown
        self.imgLeft = movingLeft
        self.imgRight = movingRight

        self.swingingUp = swingingUp
        self.swingingDown = swingingDown
        self.swingingLeft = swingingLeft
        self.swingingRight = swingingRight

        self.phase = 0
        self.imgGroup = self.imgDown
        self.image = self.imgGroup[self.phase]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.speed = speed
        self.Swinging = False

    def update(self, Scene):
        moved = False
        x = 0
        y = 0

        #Player controls
        if self.controls_Up in Scene.keys_pressed_list:
            self.imageGroup = self.imgUp
            y = -self.speed
            moved = True

        elif self.controls_Down in Scene.keys_pressed_list:
            self.imageGroup = self.imgDown
            y = self.speed
            moved = True

        elif self.controls_Left in Scene.keys_pressed_list:
            self.imageGroup = self.imgLeft
            x = -self.speed
            moved = True

        elif self.controls_Right in Scene.keys_pressed_list:
            self.imageGroup = self.imgRight
            x = self.speed
            moved = True


        elif self.controls_Swing in Scene.keys_pressed_list:

            Swinging = {
                self.imgDown : self.swingingDown,
                self.imgUp: self.swingingUp,
                self.imgLeft: self.swingingLeft,
                self.imgRight: self.swingingRight
            }

            self.imageGroup = Swinging[self.imageGroup]

            self.Swinging = True

            moved = True

        if moved or self.phase != 0:
            if moved:
                self.phase = (self.phase + 1) % 4
            else:
                self.phase = 0

            self.image = self.imageGroup[self.phase]
            self.rect.x += x
            self.rect.y += y
            self.Swinging = False
```

This is file with player class - Btw. swinging is WIP.

I am trying to make window and player that can move (WASD), but it makes only black window. What I need to know is WHY?!

- I am using python 3.6
- Hope this question isn't so stupid

Comment: @OP Your code is way too big. If you only have a black window, then remove everything and start at the beggining (changing background color and adding one image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list you add your player sprite to is not the same list you use in your `Level` instance. Take a look here:

```
...
import SpecialFunctions

Sprites = []

NewScreen = SpecialFunctions.Level('NewProject', '2D-AboveView', (960, 540), Sprites)

Sprites = []

...
```

So `NewScreen` will only ever see the first list, which is always empty, while you add your `Player_Type_AboveView` instance to another list that isn't used anywhere.

Just remove the second `Sprites = []` line.

Also, it's (most of the time) better to use a [`Group`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) instead of a list for managing your sprites.